# Generate JSON reports for values stored in a list using python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm using the VirusTotal API for sending requests of different files(in form of there hash codes) and check whether they contain any viruses or not. So, I have a list named "resources" that contains hash values of different files (around 4000 files).

I tried out the following code only for the first 10 values from "resources":

```
    for row in range(1,11):
        url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/report'
        params = {'apikey': apikey, 'resource':resources[row]}
        response = requests.get(url, params=params)
        response.json()
```

But it gives me the following error on execution:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I am not understanding what this error means and how could I rectify it. Please help.

Comment: Normally you have to put in a content type header for JSON or a different url to get JSON. Are you sure you are requesting JSON?

Comment: @DanielButler I have to put it in a content type header. Basically, I want to loop over the list "resources" to generate results for each and every file's hash code.

Comment: The error is leading me to believe that you aren’t getting json from your request. Are you able to validate that you are?

Comment: @DanielButler yes, you're correct. I'm not getting the json from my request.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `urllib` module. This code will work for `Python27`. I guess it has been refactored somewhat in `Python3x`. Please refer to https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html for more information.

Here is an updated version of the code (`Python27`). Can you please let us know if this works?

```
import urllib   
for row in range(1,11):
     url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/report'
     params = {'apikey': apikey, 'resource':resources[row]}
     urlnew = urllib.quote_plus(url) 
     paramsNew = urllib.quote_plus(params) 
     response = requests.get(urlnew, params=paramsNew)
     response.json()
```

Comment: It gives an error:
TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes